# Java: retrieving and printing out items from an arraylist using getters

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures

I am writing a program to simulate a system in a coffee shop where the person who takes the orders of the customers gives a customer a token number and enters into a system the token number of the customer along with the items s/he has ordered. The recordOrder function carries out this operation which allows order details to be input. An order is represented by a token ID, tID, and an arrayList of strings representing the items in the order.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Ques4 {

   private static class Order{
     private int tID;
     private int orderId;
     private String itemName;

    public Order(int tID,String itemName){
        this.tID=tID;
        this.itemName=itemName;

    }

    public int gettID() {
        return tID;
    }

    public void settID(int tID) {
        this.tID = tID;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    /*public String toString(){
        return "Token num: "+gettID()+ " Item name: "+getItemName();
    }*/

}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    ArrayList<Order> listOfItems= new ArrayList<Order>();
    recordOrder(listOfItems);


}

    private static void recordOrder(ArrayList<Order> listOfItems){

        int n, tnum;
        int num_Orders;
        String item = null;

        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the token number: ");
        tnum= sc.nextInt();


       System.out.println("Enter the number of items for token number: "+tnum);
       n=sc.nextInt();
       sc.nextLine();


    System.out.println("Enter the items: ");

    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){

        item=sc.nextLine();

       }
    listOfItems.add(new Order(tnum, item));


 for(Order list: listOfItems){
     System.out.println("Token num: "+list.gettID()+ " Item name: "+list.getItemName());}   


        }
  }
```

The problem is that only the last item which I enter is being printed out,that is, suppose I input token number as 9, number of items as 3 and the item names as cheesecake, burritos, tacos, only tacos is being printed out and the output will be like this:

Token num: 9 Item name: tacos

It should instead be:

Token num: 9 Item name: cheesecake burritos tacos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
    item=sc.nextLine();
    listOfItems.add(new Order(tnum, item));
}
```

Your logic of adding the items should be inside the loop. Since you are adding it outside the loop, only one element gets added(that is the last element)

**EDIT:**
to print the required way:

```
System.out.print("Token num: "+list.gettID()+ " Item name:");
for(Order list: listOfItems){
     System.out.print(" "+list.getItemName());
}   
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. But when I put it in the loop, the same line is getting printed thrice(if I input 3 items). I want a single line to be printed out with the token number and its respective items.

Comment: So change your printing logic. First print the initial part once, then loop your objects, and print them without a new line

Comment: Thanks! But actually since `list` has been declared in the loop, it won't be accessible in the above line(the system.out.printout) so I used `System.out.println("Token num: "+tnum);`

Comment: Sure:-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: And please upvote my question if you deem it right:-)

Comment: Hello, I would be glad if you could answer my ques: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140522/reading-data-from-a-text-file-to-compute-and-write-the-data-in-another-text-file

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
    item += sc.nextLine();
}

listOfItems.add(new Order(tnum, item));
```

This will append the items to the String you're building each time for the for loop, instead of overwriting the variable each time.

Comment: I would not change data structure just to print in a particular way

Answer (score 0):

If you have to add more items to one object, you will need to initialize itemName as an array of String.

```
String[] itemName;
```

And in your setter method, add to the string instead of replacing the whole value with the new one. This is why you get only the latest input value.

```
 public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName.add(itemName);
    }
```

Similarly, you can handle the getter to output the String array.